# Is it possible to fetch the links on the flash part of the web page using php?

Tags: php

I am working to fetch the links on a web page in php.The non-flash part of the web page is done but I am unable to fetch the links on the flash part of the web page.I want to know whether it is possible to fetch that using code?If so please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: You would have to parse the SWF files... not easy to do but not impossible.

Comment: @Brad:Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You need to read an SWF file, which is a proprietary format.  There is some documentation online of how they are built.  There is also an old PHP extension that is no longer maintained.  The source code is still available, so you might be able to use it as a good start:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/swf.examples-basic.php